# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'click'

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to run this script here: https://github.com/carderne/signal-export

However, when I run

```
./sigexport.py outputdir
```

I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/./sigexport.py", line 11, in <module>
    import click
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'click'
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't installed the `click` library. `pip install click` in a terminal to install it. then try again

Comment: That works, excetp now I get this error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlcipher3'

Except I have it installed, but it is not appearing in the directory. I don't know where it is supposedly installed. I keep reinstalling it, but nothing.

Comment: You'll need to install sqlcipher and the python library pysqlcipher3 with something like:

brew install sqlcipher
pip3 install pysqlcipher3 --user                                          
https://github.com/mattsta/signal-backup/issues/1

Comment: Also take care of the click's version, make sure you are installing the version which is proven to be working.

Comment: `conda install -c conda-forge click` worked, but not `pip install click --upgrade`

Comment: @lionrocker221 the library should be installed automatically by pip. What happened here? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 11):

enter in terminal:

```
sudo pip3 install Click
```